# Android Layout help

Tags: android

I am still bit new to Android layout designing. I need small help to design a layout that looks like this with dynamically loading images/text. Please advice how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's all about retrieving data from web servers.
Look for LazyList adapter implementation(googling will lead you on Stackoverflow). That's for loading images. 
Also study REST communication.

[Good tutorial for XML parsing on Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)

When you are done with this - ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `GridLayout` inflating custom views including the title and the image you want. You can always get into the inflated view to dynamically change their content (text or images).

I've found [this](http://androidexample.com/Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=75) websites wich explais you how to use them together with adapters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GridLayoutManager in RecyclerView to achieve this design and you can load images from your web server. In client side you try to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to show and cache images.
**list_item.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="80dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/country_photo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
        android:src="@drawable/three"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="@string/country_name"
        android:textColor="@color/accent_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/country_photo"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/color_primary_dark"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

private List<ItemObject> itemList;
private Context context;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<ItemObject> itemList) {
    this.itemList = itemList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, null);
    RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
    return rcv;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
    holder.countryName.setText(itemList.get(position).getName());
    holder.countryPhoto.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getPhoto());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.itemList.size();
}
}
```

**RecyclerViewHolders**

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

public TextView countryName;
public ImageView countryPhoto;

public RecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    countryName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
    countryPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Clicked Country Position = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private GridLayoutManager lLayout;

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setTitle(null);

    Toolbar topToolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(topToolBar);
    topToolBar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
    topToolBar.setLogoDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.logo_desc));

    List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
    lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 4);

    RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    rView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

    RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, rowListItem);
    rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
  }
 @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if(id == R.id.action_refresh){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Refresh App", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    if(id == R.id.action_new){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Create Text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }

   private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){

    List<ItemObject> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United States", R.drawable.one));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Canada", R.drawable.two));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United Kingdom", R.drawable.three));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Germany", R.drawable.four));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Sweden", R.drawable.five));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United Kingdom", R.drawable.six));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Germany", R.drawable.seven));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Sweden", R.drawable.eight));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United States", R.drawable.one));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Canada", R.drawable.two));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United Kingdom", R.drawable.three));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Germany", R.drawable.four));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Sweden", R.drawable.five));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United Kingdom", R.drawable.six));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Germany", R.drawable.seven));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Sweden", R.drawable.eight));

    return allItems;
}
}
```

This code might be helpful for you.